# How to get more info from foursquare place api

Tags: foursquare

We are developing API for our mobile application and we are using Foursquare Places API. We got a problem with this end-point: "GET https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search". We need to display venue photo and rating, but they don't provide such info in this end-point. Would appreciate if you could help us to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

REST endpoints are very task-specific. `/search` is just for getting search results. If you want details of a venue, use this one:

`GET https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID`

Their API is [very well documented](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/details).

Comment: We have a screen displaying found search results. On that screen we are showing title, photo, rating, etc. Let's say search gets 5 results. In this case I have to make 1 request to search end-point and 5 more requests to get details about each venue? 
I'm not sure if this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out foursquare postman collection https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/postman 
it is awesome.

There you may find request you need.

For instance request presents the most detailed info about venue:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{{VENUE_ID}}?client_id={{client_id}}&client_secret={{client_secret}}&v={{v}}
```